# Scheme: reverse is not taking any affect

Tags: recursion, scheme, reverse, let

```
(define key
  (lambda (w)
    (reverse w)
    (if (null? w)
     0
    (let ((k 33))
         (+ (* (ctv(car w)) k) (key (cdr w)))
))))
```

outputs the same thing as this:

```
(define key
  (lambda (w)
    (if (null? w)
     0
    (let ((k 33))
         (+ (* (ctv(car w)) k) (key (cdr w)))
))))
```

Why isn't my word reversed and then computed?

Input: (key '(x y z))

Output: 2475 (for both methods)

I don't understand why this happens. Someone please help me see why this is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed, the [`reverse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._reverse%29%29) procedure returns a *new* list, it doesn't modify in-place the list that was passed as a parameter (this happens with all the procedures that modify lists, be careful with it). That's the reason why the line `(reverse w)` in your code doesn't have any effect: surely it returns a new reversed list, but you ignored the value that was returned!

For using the reversed list, you have to store or pass it along somewhere, a good idea would be to save it in a local variable defined inside a `let` form and refer to the variable from that point on. This is what @michaelb958 is suggesting:

```
(define key
  (lambda (w)
    (let ((w (reverse w)))
      (if (null? w)
          0
          (let ((k 33))
            (+ (* (ctv (car w)) k) (key (cdr w))))))))
```

However, be warned that the above will reverse the `w` list *each time* the recursion is called as it traverses the list, I don't think that's what you intend! if you need to reverse the list only *once*, call `reverse` *before* calling `key`, and don't ever call `reverse` *inside* `key`:

```
(key (reverse '(x y z)))
```

Comment: How would you do this? Where can I call reverse so I only call it once in my case?

Comment: OH! In my main method perhaps!

Comment: @SolBethanyReaves that's right, that's the best place to do it. Definitely _not_ in `key`, otherwise you'd be reversing, re-reversing, re-re-reversing the list each time the recursion gets called ... you get the idea ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was pondering how to do this for hours. XD

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` just returns the reversed list, rather than reversing it in place. You'll need to

```
(let ((w (reverse w)))
  ...)
```

to get the effect you want.

Comment: It outputs the same thing. :(

Comment: Suggestion: Your code is now `(define key (lambda (w) (reverse w) your-other-code))`. Change it to `(define key (lambda (w) (let ((w (reverse w))) your-other-code)))`.

Comment: It does something funny: It "reverses" the list '(x y z) to '(y x z)

Answer (score 1):

Since, as others have noted, `reverse` does not reverse in place, your code should be modified as:

```
(define key
  (lambda (w)
    (set! w (reverse w))                ; CHANGE IS HERE
    (if (null? w)
         0
         (let ((k 33))
           (+ (* (ctv (car w)) k)
              (key (cdr w)))))))
```

Note, you are recursively calling `key` and thus you will be reversing back and forth, again and again.